# How can get only key values from the join() values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, html

```
const myQuestions =  [
        {
                level:"Level 1",
                questionNo: 1,
                sentence: "Her uncles are army officers.",
                question: "Q . Which words are about people? ",
                answers: {
                    "1": "a. uncles / officers",
                    "2": "b. her/are",
                    "3": "c. in/the"
                },
                correctAnswer: "1",
                topic: "Noun",
                description: "plural nouns"
            },
            {
                level:"Level 1",
                questionNo: 2,
                sentence: "He dropped the glass and it broke into many pieces.",
                question: "Q . Which word stands for 'the glass'?",
                answers: {
                    "1": "a. he",
                    "2": "b. it",
                    "3": "c. into"
                },
                correctAnswer: "2",
                topic: "Pronoun",
                description: "pronoun  'it' and what it has already referred to"
            },
     ....
     ]
```

This is my JSON. Here my Html5 codes below

```
<div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
```

Now we got key and values also like this.

1: a. uncles / officers

But we want only values. Anybody can solve this bug?

Comment: What is `answers`?

Comment: How are you creating `answers` from `myQuestions[i].answers`?

Comment: Use `Object.values(myQuestions[i].answers)` to get just the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values()` for this:

```
${Object.values(answers).join("")}
```

```js
const myQuestions = [{
  level: "Level 1",
  questionNo: 1,
  sentence: "Her uncles are army officers.",
  question: "Q . Which words are about people? ",
  answers: {
    "1": "a. uncles / officers",
    "2": "b. her/are",
    "3": "c. in/the"
  },
  correctAnswer: "1",
  topic: "Noun",
  description: "plural nouns"
}];

console.log(Object.values(myQuestions[0].answers).join(', '));
```

Comment: i got same result

Comment: didn't get you. What is the output? Is it as same as you got in your post?

Comment: its working. but i have n no of arrays. what can we do?

Comment: _n no of arrays_ of questions or answers?

Comment: yes it is contain n no of arrays of questions or answers

Comment: can you post a sample of it to have a look at it.

Comment: Okay. You need a loop to iterate over it and you should then use `${Object.values(answers[i]).join("")}` where `i` is the iteration index.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
answers.join("")
```

then the `join` method is applied to the entire `answers` object, and it will concatenate both its keys and values.

In order to feed only the values to `join`, do:

```
Object.values(answers).join("")
```

More specifically:

```
var answers = myQuestions[0].answers;
console.log(Object.values(answers).join(""));
```

(as shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/IndependentSw/pen/xJjvRM)).

Comment: but i get the same result

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myQuestions = [{
  level: "Level 1",
  questionNo: 1,
  sentence: "Her uncles are army officers.",
  question: "Q . Which words are about people? ",
  answers: {
    "1": "a. uncles / officers",
    "2": "b. her/are",
    "3": "c. in/the"
  },
  correctAnswer: "1",
  topic: "Noun",
  description: "plural nouns"
}]


const ans = Object.values(myQuestions[0].answers)

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: this is enough?